# Right syntax of Hyperlink NavigateUrl

Tags: c#, asp.net

In `Index.aspx` page, I use a Hyperlink and pass to `ShowIndexRegular.aspx` 2 variables: key and flag

```
{
     ........
     string key="3";
     string flag="0";
     HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = string.Format("ShowIndexRegular.aspx?key={0},flag={1}",key,flag);

}
```

In `ShowIndexRegular.aspx`:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(Request.QueryString["flag"]!=null)
            {
                string key="";
                string flag = "";
                string result="";                
flag = Request.QueryString["flag"].ToString();

                if (flag.Equals(0))
                {
                    key = Request.QueryString["key"].ToString();

                }
                else if (flag.Equals("1"))
                {
                    ....
                }
                result="1";

            }
            else
            {
                result="0";
            }

         }
```

When I click on the Hyperlink1 in `Index.aspx`, even when the the Addressbar shows: `http://localhost:41148/website/ShowIndexRegular.aspx?key=3,flag=0`

The `result is always "0"`, it means the flag is null. I really dont know why, the addressbar showes that: `key=3,flag=0.`

Is there any mistake on my Hyperlink NavigateURL syntax???
Help!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query strings don't separate key/value pairs by comma:

```
ShowIndexRegular.aspx?key={0},flag={1}
```

Instead, they separate key/value pairs by ampersand:

```
ShowIndexRegular.aspx?key={0}&flag={1}
```

Answer (score 1):

See below.

```
HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = string.Format("ShowIndexRegular.aspx?key={0}&flag={1}",key,flag);
```

You were trying to build your querystring using a wrong format. Replace your code with what i have above and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right way to pass multi pair of QueryString, you will simply need to use "&" instead of "," like below:

{
         ........
         string key="3";
         string flag="0";
         HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = string.Format("ShowIndexRegular.aspx?key={0}&flag={1}",key,flag);

```
}
```